# Express enforce SSL on Heroku

Tags: angular, express, ssl, heroku, server-side-rendering

Here is my `server.ts` file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import express from 'express';
import path, { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

const compression = require('compression');

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();

  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/bookni-to/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();

  // SSL
  server.enable('trust proxy');
  server.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.secure ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  });

  // Compression
  server.use(compression());

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}


// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Here is the part where I am trying to enforce SSL:

```
server.enable('trust proxy');
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.secure ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
});
```

Express version

```
4.17.1
```

Packages that I have tried and did not work:

- ssl-express-www
- heroku-ssl-redirect
- force-ssl-heroku

My hypothesis is that it maybe does not belong to the run() function but I cannot see other place where it could go.

Comment: I'm using the exact same pattern for my Angular Universal applications at Heroku, but the middleware is defined in the app function, not run()

Comment: I gave it a shot and it finally worked. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome. Always glad to help.